# Multiple permissions as single integer in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, enums

I'm working on a forum, and i wanna save user permissions in DB.
My idea is this:

```
USER TABLE HAS: (besides name, login etc)
fk_role_id

ROLE TABLE HAS:
role_id
role_name
role_rights
```

Then i have a `Enum` with user rights and a user class:

```
[Flags] public enum PermissionTypes : int {
    None = 0,
    Register = 1,
    ThreadCreate = 2,
    ThreadEdit = 4,
    ThreadDelete = 8,
    ReplyCreate = 16,
    ReplyEdit = 32,
    ReplyDelete = 64,
    CatCreate = 128,
    CatEdit = 256,
    CatDelete = 512,
    UserCreate = 1024,
    UserEdit = 2048,
    UserDelete = 4096,

    All = Register | ThreadCreate | ThreadEdit | ThreadDelete | ReplyCreate | ReplyEdit | ReplyDelete | CatCreate | CatEdit | CatDelete | UserCreate | UserEdit | UserDelete
}

public class User {
    public PermissionTypes Permissions = PermissionTypes.None;
}
```

Now is it possible to save user rights as a int in `role_rights` ? and get them out again offcourse?

UPDATE:

Just to clearify what my problem is...
Fx. if i have a user with permissions: CatCreate & UserCreate, that would give me a total of: 1152...
Now how would i use that number to test what permissions the user has? now that it's a single decimal

Comment: What do you think you are saving by doing it this way? http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle

Comment: But what is the problem? Surely you know how to store an integer and query it?

Comment: Just updated my question...  And i guess im trying not, having to make a table with functions user can access, and another one to bind the functions the a role...
So with this i only need a Role table, with a decimal, and from that i can see what the user can access...

Comment: First: why save it as a decimal? If it's an int, save it as an int. Second: see my answer. You have 1152 stored in a variable `pValue`. Now `((pValue & PermissionTypes.CatCreate) == PermissionTypes.CatCreate)` will be true, as will `((pValue & PermissionTypes.CatCreate) == PermissionTypes.UserCreate)`. But `((pValue & PermissionTypes.ThreadDelete) == PermissionTypes.ThreadDelete)` will be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to check for a certain value, for example "CatDelete", you do: `Permissions & PermissionTypes.CatDelete == PermissionTypes.CatDelete`.

To remove one value: `Permissions &= ~PermissionTypes.CatDelete`

To add one value: `Permissions |= PermissionTypes.CatDelete`

Comment: Yes, but my question is how i would save a users permissions in DB...
When using this approach...

Comment: Something like `"UPDATE Users SET Permissions = " + (int)Permissions + " WHERE ID=" + ID`... but please use sqlcommand + parameters for this. ^^;

Comment: Okay, if you have a separate "Roles" Table, you might need to have an intermediate n to m table "UserRoles or something. Where you just have UserID and RoleID (and the combination of both is unique). you can't just have one "combined" FK-field in your Users table.

Comment: Well the idea is that "Roles" Table has a list of Roles like Admin, User, etc.. And the "Role_Rights" contains permissions, in a single decimal.. so why i would need another table, i dont see. that just seems like a waste

Comment: Okay, so save the `int` value of the Permissions property in `Role_Rights`. Now User U has a reference to Role 27 which has a `Role_Rights` of 160. So `(Role_Rights & 128) = 128` and `(Role_Rights & 32) = 32` should return true, meaning User U has both CatCreate and ReplyEdit. Anything else, like `(Role_Rights & 8) = 8` should return false, meaning User U does NOT have the right ThreadDelete.

Comment: Okay, so i just created a user, setting `user.Permissions = PermissionTypes.CatCreate | PermissionTypes.UserCreate;`
That gives me a value of 1152, wich i for testing purpose just put in a `int` called pValue. now i dont see how i would take `pValue` and see what user permissions are set?

Comment: Other way 'round. User want's to do something like deleting a thread. To delete a thread, the User must have the Permission `ThreadDelete` so you check `if ((User.Permission & Permissions.ThreadDelete) == Permissions.ThreadDelete) { [delete the thread] } else { [access denied] }`.

Comment: Yes... again that depends on having the User.Permission object filled with the individual permissions... fx. when a user log's in, i would only have the total value of 1152 to work with. So what would i do with that number, to get my permission object filled.

Comment: By "permission object" you mean the property `User.Permissions`? Then you can just cast the int to the enum: `User.Permissions = (PermissionTypes)1152;`.

Comment: Yes sorry, property :)
ahhh didnt know that you could do that, guess that me missing some understanding of Enum... well that solved my problem! :) thanks!